# Unable to test Angular service with Console constructor parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to implement a logging service as the name service implies.
A concrete implementation of the logging service will be resolved at initialization time.
This concrete implementation is using the console to log the messages.
I need the `Console` in the constructor to be able to mock it without affecting the global `console` object.

I had the same test run on Jasmine and it would pass just fine. Also it works fine in the application, so I think it has something to do with Jest or its configuration.

I am trying to inject the Console interface into my Angular service like this:

```js
export class ConsoleLoggerService implements LoggerService {
   constructor(public console: Console) { }
}
```

When I try to run my test:

```js
describe('ConsoleLoggerService', () => {
  let service: ConsoleLoggerService;
  let consoleMock: Console;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    consoleMock = {
      log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) { }
    } as Console;
    service = new ConsoleLoggerService(consoleMock);
  }));
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I get this error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Console is not defined

       9 | export class ConsoleLoggerService implements LoggerService {
      10 |
    > 11 |   constructor(public console: Console) { }
         |                               ^
```

In my understanding the `Console` interface comes from `@types/node` and should be available globally.
Why does my test fail then?

I am using Angular 9, Jest 24.9 and Nx 9 for my workspace.

Comment: I updated my answer based on what you said

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that console log was hit use jest to mock it. In your test you could do something like this:

```
it('console.log the text "hello"', () => {
  console.log = jest.fn();

  // call some function here that will end up doing your logging

  // The first argument of the first call to the function was 'hello'
  expect(console.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('hello');
});
```

If you're just injecting it like that for testing purposes I would recommend just using jest to mock it like above.

If you have to keep injecting it like that you can use the testbed to provide a fake provider:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        // MockConsole would be some fake class that you create
        providers: [{provide: Console, useClass: MockConsole }]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(CgonsoleLoggerService);
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this replace the log function globally?

Comment: Added a more detailed description in the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: It is possible to inject the `Console` like this, you just need to provide it something like
{ provide: 'Console', useValue: console }

Comment: yeah, so if you do it that way you would also need to do the same thing in your test as well.

Comment: No it would not replace it globally would just replace it for that test

Comment: Now it throws inside the test where I mention the Console interface.
The test passes well with no changes if I set the type to any inside the service.
It seems it cannot resolve the type itself as it cannot see it exist.
I have a feeling it might be related to the "testEnvironment" setting in Jest.

Comment: That could be, I would try the jest.fn() approach if possible so that you don't have to worry about the types